# Would like to understand how to call javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.getHeader(String) from Eclipse when debugging

Tags: java, linux, eclipse

I am trying to debug the security functionality of our web application. To do so, I'd like to be able to impersonate another user.

It looks like the code somehow interfaces with Web Seal to get the current user's LAN ID and list of global groups or something that closely resembles real global groups. Our application has a cross reference table that seems to relate the two. I'm not sure what is the significance of this mapping.

It uses this method:

```
javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.getHeader(String)
```

to get the LAN ID and "groups" that the LAN ID belongs to

```
userLANID = request.getHeader("iv-user");
userGroup = request.getHeader("iv-groups");
```

When I debug this in Spring Tool Suite, both method calls return null. So, I hard code userLANID to my LAN ID value and userGroup to a value that I was provided by a colleague.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to have this function call work on my local machine when debugging interactively but I don't know what is underneath the function. Do you think that it is likely a custom function that was developed in house to somehow get the user's global groups from Web Seal?

Question 1:
*How can I get these 2 lines of code which call the getHeader method to work on my PC when debugging or do I have to continue to debug by hard coding these two values for me?** I'd like to know what the values are being returned for other users in order to ensure that I can impersonate them properly when testing.

**Question 2:**
What is the underlying mechanism of this call? Does it involve some custom component that I can't see in the Java source?

I'm not a Java developer. This app runs on Linux. I'm not a Linux guy, either, so I am out of my area but I have Windows .NET dev experience.